# If it is possible to always run remote-ssh and Live Share on my server?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote, vscode-liveshare

I want to have a server always running Live Share so that I don't have to always have a computer opening the VSCode window to keep Live Share alive. I tried to run Live Share on my server through Remote-SSH extension, however, when I close the window, the Live share will shut down along with the Remote-SSH session.

Is it possible to have Live Share always run on my server?

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue is described and resolved here [Live share not working on Remote SSH session](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/live-share/issues/3392)

According to that discussion thread there are three places to have "Live share" installed:

```
1) Locally in: local_machine:~/.vscode

2) Remotely in the VSCode server (via Remote Development (SSH)) remote_machine:~/.vscode-server

3) The actual remote environment: remote_machine:~/.vscode
```

In their case, which is similar if not the same as yours, VS Live Share was not installed in remote_machine:~/.vscode

Installing in that final location solved the issue.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you close the SSH window, you terminate the session and any processes started in the session will either be terminated or suspended.

Have it run as a service that starts after each boot instead of starting it as a user process.